# Is it possible to use the LexicalizedParser class to do 'pure' dependency parsing?

Tags: parsing, stanford-nlp

I am trying to use the Stanford NLP toolkit to evaluate dependency grammars.

Is it possible to make the LexicalizedParser class use **only** the rules from the DEPENDENCY_GRAMMAR section of the model file?

Leaving the other sections of the model file blank causes exceptions, and changing the 'doPCFG' flag to 'false' in the model file causes a null pointer exception in ExhaustiveDependencyParser.getBestScore.

It appears that the LexicalizeParser class falls back on the (constituency) PCFG when it cannot parse the input using the dependency rules.

Is this correct? Can this behaviour be switched off so that dependency grammars can be evaluated in isolation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [Stanford Dependency Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/nndep.shtml), which only produces a dependency parser and not a constituency parse. The lexicalized parser, by contrast, only produces a constituency parse, which is then converted to a dependency parse with a converter. Therefore, there is no option to not produce this constituency parse and still produce a dependency parse, as there's nothing for the converter to convert.

If you're only doing evaluation of grammatical formalisms, however, you may consider using the dependency converter on gold trees, or using the new Universal Dependencies annotated data.

Comment: I considered the Stanford Dependency Parser, but it's based on a neural network and it's models consist of feature vectors, rather than traditional grammar rules. Is it possible to load a dependency grammar in, or would it just be a case of training it?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there's no such thing as a "dependency grammar" in the sense of the grammar of a PCFG parser. All dependency parsers I know of have some equivalent of a dependency arc classifier of some sort -- whether this is for scoring arcs in an MST algorithm, or scoring parse actions in a shift-reduce framework. The neural parser is no exception; it just uses a neural net for its classifier.

Comment: Of course.. I was just thinking of the sort of representations used in the DEPENDENCY_GRAMMAR section of the LexicalizedParser models, which can be read and evaluated by a human much more easily than a 50 element vector.

e.g.: `"than/IN" -> "leader/NN" left 0 1.0 `
vs 
`tied -0.6479344878343402 0.5893377057407623 1.0174283134652544     0.7000564156722917 -0.004831055643038269 ... ... ...     0.7715736625830979`

Comment: Did you use one of our pre-trained models or your own? If you use one of our pre-trained models than make sure that you use englishFactored.ser.gz instead of englishPCFG.ser.gz because the latter doesn't extract a dependency grammar. If you train your own model make sure to use the `-dep` flag during training and testing, otherwise it won't extract a dependency grammar either. `java edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -dep edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishFactored.ser.gz` generates a dependency tree for me without throwing an exception.